# Exponential transformation of Bernuolli variable

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, bernoulli-distribution

Assuming that $x$ is a Bernoulli random variable with probability $p$, let $Y = 2^X3^{(1-X)}$,

What is the pmf of $Y$
What is $E[Y]$

What is $Var[Y]$

I have never seen an exponential transformation and I have been a bit puzzled by this. If the equation follows Bernuolli's equation then $p = 2$ or $q = 3$ or the other way round but $p,q$ can't be larger than 1. Please help me out.

Comment: $X$ has only two possible values: $0$ and $1.$  Plug them into the formula for $Y.$

Comment: @whuber but the pmf cant be larger than 1, and I'm getting p(0) = 3 and p(1) = 2

Comment: How do you get p(0) = 3 and p(1)=2? Show your work.

Comment: I assume you've figured it out by now, but in case you haven't - $Y$ is just a number, it's not the pmf you are interested in for expected value and variance calculations.  $p(Y=2) = p(X=1)$.  Can you see why?